# ListView item style keeps changing randomly when there are multiple style in the same ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have made a chat application where the chat view is formed from many rows in a `ListView` where messages sent by the user are displaying in white and messages received by friend are displayed in blue.

This behavior works fine, but when I scroll the list after becoming really big (e.g. 30 rows) the colors are messed. I use different layouts for each row, white row layout and blue row layout.

When I scroll multiple times up and down the list the colors keeps switching randomly (i.e. some of my messages are in blue and others in white, and some of the other end (the friend chatting with me) becomes white and other messages become blue in a random way.

I'll give you a snipped preview on the code used:

This is the `getView` method in my custom adapter which extends `BaseAdapter`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        final int pos = position;                           
        String from = messages.get(pos).getFrom();
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();    
                     // If message is sent by me (the user)
            if(from.toString().toLowerCase().equals("me")){
               convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_msg_row2, null);
            }
                    // if message is sent by his friend (the other end user)
            else{
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_msg_row, null);           
            }

            holder.userName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgusername);
            holder.userImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ppic);
                holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgdate);
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msg);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }           
        holder.userName.setText( messages.get(pos).getFrom() );
        holder.text.setText( messages.get(pos).getText() );
        holder.date.setText( messages.get(pos).getDate() );         
        String img = messages.get(pos).getImage();          
        if(img.substring(0,4).equalsIgnoreCase("http") ){

            try{
                  ImageLoader imloader = new ImageLoader( ChatActivity.this );      
                          holder.userImage.setTag(img);
              imloader.DisplayImage( img, ChatActivity.this , holder.userImage );
                }
            catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();                      
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position){
         return 1;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView userName;
        ImageView userImage;
        TextView text;
        TextView date;
    }
```

The two layouts, `chat_msg_row2` and `chat_msg_row`, are identical except for the Drawable used, where one is using a white image and the other using a blue image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't use the `getItemViewType` and the `getViewTypeCount` methods of the adapter, then the `ListView` will assume you only have one type of row(although you actually use two types) and will recycle rows as they appear in the list. So, when the `convertView` is not `null` you get a recycled row that could be either one of those two types depending on its position.

But the methods above should be implemented only if your rows are really different(extra widgets, placement rules etc). If your two rows are different **only by the background image** then you need only one row and you'll be setting the background based on your app's logic, something like this:

```
//...
if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();    
    // just inflate one of the rows if they are identical
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_msg_row, parent, false);           
    holder.userName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgusername);
    holder.userImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ppic);
    holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgdate);
    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msg);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}           
// set the background image as desired   
if(from.toString().toLowerCase().equals("me")){
    // I assumed you set the background on the root of the View row, convertView
    // otherwise search for the desired view in convertView and set the background
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.the_me_background_drawable);
} else {
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.the_other_user_background_drawable);
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced similar problem. What I did was remove the

```
if (convertView == null)
```

and the return the View itself. What that above code does is : it checks if there are previous cache present in the present list. If present it re-uses previously present list. Hope it helps